# kivy app is blurry on windows with high resolution screen

Tags: python, kivy, screen-resolution

I am having trouble with my kivy app. The text is blurry on my high resolution windows laptop (3840x2160). It works fine on a Mac with retina display and on a windows PC lower resolution. As seen in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot of app]

This is my test code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '100')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="why is this blurry")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

And this the console output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\lucas\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-04-01_6.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\lucas\kivytest\env\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)][INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\lucas\kivytest\env\Scripts\python.exe"       
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.14757 Compatibility Profile Context FireGL 20.45.01.45 27.20.14501.45003'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ATI Technologies Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'AMD Radeon(TM) Pro Graphics'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

This issues seems to be related to this: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3705

or this: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/7299

or this: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/7293

But none of the suggestions seem to work for me. Any idea how to reslove this?

Comment: I have no idea of Kivy apps but I’d  give more resolution 1000 instead of 200 and then check it.

Comment: Best guess is that Mac translates the pixels from point system and the Window is trying to translating pixels in literally.

Comment: @NaveedAbbas: I just did that for the screen-shot so one can see the letters in the background. Increasing this doesn't change anything regarding the blurriness, it just makes the window larger.

Comment: AFAIK OpenGL renders the text as Graphics, seems like the converter is by default set to use low resolution. Look at the texture Max units. Btw Windows has a text antialiasing settings as well, did you check them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is basically in the second link that I posted : https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/7299

I also posted a question in that thread when I didn't get any responses here, but will copy my solution here.

When I did the following:

```
from ctypes import windll
windll.user32.SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(-4)
lastError = windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
print(lastError)
```

I got the error 87 which corresponds to ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. So  something had to be wrong with the -4. I dug around the windll and found the following fix:

```
from ctypes import windll, c_int64
windll.user32.SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(c_int64(-4))
```

Answer (score 2):

The second link you posted provided this information:

```
from ctypes import windll
windll.user32.SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(-4)
```

Now this does not work, so we have to add `c_int64`, something found in the same module.

```
from ctypes import windll, c_int64
windll.user32.SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(c_int64(-4))
```

Now it will work!

Edit: I did not realize earlier that you had already figured it out!

Comment: yeah, i figured it out myself. that's also me in the github thread